# Pivot is leaking

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, memory, memory-leaks, mvvm-light

Just another post about leak hunting.

Situation is quite simple: I have a pivot. Pivot has event

```
SelectionChanged="MainPivot_OnSelectionChanged"
```

Event handler is simple

```
private void MainPivot_OnSelectionChanged(object _sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs _e)
{
    SimpleLogger.WriteLine(GetHashCode());
}
```

I'm using MVVM Light, and the DataContext is set via VMLocator.
Also, i'm using a [Nonlinear Navigation Service](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/13/solving-circular-navigation-in-windows-phone-silverlight-applications.aspx), because in my application loops are possible, and i want to avoid them.

However, after some time of using my app, after 1 swiping MainPivot, in the output, i see

> 11:49:47.677 [00:01:36.9350000] 133186921
>
> 11:49:47.727 [00:00:00.0360000] 133188577
>
> 11:49:47.744 [00:00:00.0140000] 133186126
>
> 11:49:47.761 [00:00:00.0150000] 133188679
>
> 11:49:47.777 [00:00:00.0140000] 133188587

That means, I have 5 instances of MainPivot view. So, question is: how to figure out, what prevents them from being collected?

PS: I'm using `InvokeCommandAction` instead of `EventToCommand`.